# Is there any ability to enable Hyper-V role on Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: hyper-v

Is there any ability to enable Hyper-V role on Hyper-V virtual machine?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCgQW.png "Hyper-V cannot be installed"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKz6h.png "Processor settings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Hyper-V does not emulate the hardware virtualization features of the CPU that are required.  Even if it did your would not like the performance of the nested Hyper-V VMs.